# query with 2 in clauses (Derby, JPA): Subquery is only allowed to return a single column

Tags: sql, jpa, derby

I have an error on this query:

```
SELECT p FROM Polizza p  WHERE p.nrPolizza IN ( 
      SELECT r.nrPolizza FROM Rate r WHERE r.idRate IN ( 
           SELECT q.iDRata FROM Pagamenti q WHERE 
                     q.pagante.codiceFiscale LIKE :pagante OR 
                     q.pagante.nome LIKE :pagante OR 
                     q.pagante.cognome LIKE :pagante 
           )
      )
```

I am using java8, jpa eclipse persistance and Derby database.
The error says that ' Subquery is only allowed to return a single column.' but in the select of the IN clause, there is only one column already selected.

How could I solve this? 
thanks

the error is:

```
    [EL Warning]: 2015-04-22 10:29:31.937--UnitOfWork(782315816)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: La subquery può restituire solo una colonna singola.
Error Code: 30000
Call: SELECT t0.NRPOLIZZA, t0.DATAINIZIO, t0.NOTE, t0.SCADCONTRATTO, t0.Beneficiario, t0.Contraente, t0.Frazionamento, t0.Proprietario, t0.StatoPolizza, t0.Tipo, t0.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t0 WHERE t0.NRPOLIZZA IN (SELECT t1.NRPOLIZZA, t1.DATAINIZIO, t1.NOTE, t1.SCADCONTRATTO, t1.Beneficiario, t1.Contraente, t1.Frazionamento, t1.Proprietario, t1.StatoPolizza, t1.Tipo, t1.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.RATE t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t1 ON (t1.NRPOLIZZA = t2.NrPolizza) WHERE t2.IDRATE IN (SELECT t3.IDRATE, t3.ABBUONO, t3.IMPORTORATA, t3.SALDATA, t3.SCADRATA, t3.TIPORATA, t3.NrPolizza FROM assicurazionedb.PAGAMENTI t4 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.RATE t3 ON (t3.IDRATE = t4.IDRata), assicurazionedb.ANAGRAFICA t5 WHERE (((t5.CODICEFISCALE LIKE ? OR t5.NOME LIKE ?) OR t5.COGNOME LIKE ?) AND (t5.CODICEFISCALE = t4.Pagante))))
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Polizza sql="SELECT t0.NRPOLIZZA, t0.DATAINIZIO, t0.NOTE, t0.SCADCONTRATTO, t0.Beneficiario, t0.Contraente, t0.Frazionamento, t0.Proprietario, t0.StatoPolizza, t0.Tipo, t0.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t0 WHERE t0.NRPOLIZZA IN (SELECT t1.NRPOLIZZA, t1.DATAINIZIO, t1.NOTE, t1.SCADCONTRATTO, t1.Beneficiario, t1.Contraente, t1.Frazionamento, t1.Proprietario, t1.StatoPolizza, t1.Tipo, t1.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.RATE t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t1 ON (t1.NRPOLIZZA = t2.NrPolizza) WHERE t2.IDRATE IN (SELECT t3.IDRATE, t3.ABBUONO, t3.IMPORTORATA, t3.SALDATA, t3.SCADRATA, t3.TIPORATA, t3.NrPolizza FROM assicurazionedb.PAGAMENTI t4 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.RATE t3 ON (t3.IDRATE = t4.IDRata), assicurazionedb.ANAGRAFICA t5 WHERE (((t5.CODICEFISCALE LIKE ? OR t5.NOME LIKE ?) OR t5.COGNOME LIKE ?) AND (t5.CODICEFISCALE = t4.Pagante))))")
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I tryed to do another query, skipping the dot notation for the table 'anagrafica' but I got the same error.

```
SELECT p FROM Polizza p  WHERE p.nrPolizza IN ( 
   SELECT r.nrPolizza FROM Rate r WHERE r.idRate IN ( 
        SELECT q.iDRata FROM Pagamenti q WHERE q.pagante IN (
             SELECT a.codiceFiscale FROM Anagrafica a WHERE 
                      a.codiceFiscale LIKE :pagante OR 
                      a.nome LIKE :pagante OR 
                      a.cognome LIKE :pagante
              )
         )
 )
```

error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2015-04-22 11:04:47.384--UnitOfWork(939627839)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: La subquery può restituire solo una colonna singola.
Error Code: 30000
Call: SELECT t0.NRPOLIZZA, t0.DATAINIZIO, t0.NOTE, t0.SCADCONTRATTO, t0.Beneficiario, t0.Contraente, t0.Frazionamento, t0.Proprietario, t0.StatoPolizza, t0.Tipo, t0.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t0 WHERE t0.NRPOLIZZA IN (SELECT t1.NRPOLIZZA, t1.DATAINIZIO, t1.NOTE, t1.SCADCONTRATTO, t1.Beneficiario, t1.Contraente, t1.Frazionamento, t1.Proprietario, t1.StatoPolizza, t1.Tipo, t1.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.RATE t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t1 ON (t1.NRPOLIZZA = t2.NrPolizza) WHERE t2.IDRATE IN (SELECT t3.IDRATE, t3.ABBUONO, t3.IMPORTORATA, t3.SALDATA, t3.SCADRATA, t3.TIPORATA, t3.NrPolizza FROM assicurazionedb.PAGAMENTI t4 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.RATE t3 ON (t3.IDRATE = t4.IDRata) WHERE t4.Pagante IN (SELECT t5.CODICEFISCALE.t5.CODICEFISCALE FROM assicurazionedb.ANAGRAFICA t5 WHERE ((t5.CODICEFISCALE LIKE ? OR t5.NOME LIKE ?) OR t5.COGNOME LIKE ?))))
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Polizza sql="SELECT t0.NRPOLIZZA, t0.DATAINIZIO, t0.NOTE, t0.SCADCONTRATTO, t0.Beneficiario, t0.Contraente, t0.Frazionamento, t0.Proprietario, t0.StatoPolizza, t0.Tipo, t0.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t0 WHERE t0.NRPOLIZZA IN (SELECT t1.NRPOLIZZA, t1.DATAINIZIO, t1.NOTE, t1.SCADCONTRATTO, t1.Beneficiario, t1.Contraente, t1.Frazionamento, t1.Proprietario, t1.StatoPolizza, t1.Tipo, t1.Veicolo FROM assicurazionedb.RATE t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.POLIZZA t1 ON (t1.NRPOLIZZA = t2.NrPolizza) WHERE t2.IDRATE IN (SELECT t3.IDRATE, t3.ABBUONO, t3.IMPORTORATA, t3.SALDATA, t3.SCADRATA, t3.TIPORATA, t3.NrPolizza FROM assicurazionedb.PAGAMENTI t4 LEFT OUTER JOIN assicurazionedb.RATE t3 ON (t3.IDRATE = t4.IDRata) WHERE t4.Pagante IN (SELECT t5.CODICEFISCALE.t5.CODICEFISCALE FROM assicurazionedb.ANAGRAFICA t5 WHERE ((t5.CODICEFISCALE LIKE ? OR t5.NOME LIKE ?) OR t5.COGNOME LIKE ?))))")
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
```

And the query I tried on the database and worked good:

```
SELECT * FROM Polizza p  WHERE p.nrPolizza IN (
     SELECT r.nrPolizza FROM Rate r WHERE r.idRate IN (
         SELECT q.iDRata FROM Pagamenti q WHERE q.pagante IN (
               SELECT a.codicefiscale FROM Anagrafica a WHERE
                      a.codicefiscale LIKE 'Matteo' OR
                      a.nome LIKE 'Matteo' OR 
                      a.cognome LIKE 'Matteo'
               )
         )
      )
```

Edit1:
edited alias
Edit2: 
edited query
Edit3:
Solved.

Hi, I have solved the issue: also if the query worked good if executed in the database, there was an error in the Jpa query: 
the **'r.nrPolizza'** it's really an object of type **Polizza**, so in order to compare the **'p.nrPolizza'** (Integer) it have to be: **'r.nrPolizza.nrPolizza'**.
So the query

```
SELECT p FROM Polizza p  WHERE p.nrPolizza IN ( 
       SELECT r.nrPolizza.nrPolizza FROM Rate r WHERE r.idRate IN ( 
            SELECT q.iDRata.idRate FROM Pagamenti q WHERE q.pagante.codiceFiscale IN (
                 SELECT a.codiceFiscale FROM Anagrafica a WHERE 
                          a.codiceFiscale LIKE :pagante OR 
                          a.nome LIKE :pagante OR 
                          a.cognome LIKE :pagante
                  )
             )
     )
```

or

```
SELECT p FROM Polizza p  WHERE p.nrPolizza IN  
       (SELECT DISTINCT q.iDRata.nrPolizza.nrPolizza FROM Pagamenti q WHERE q.pagante IN  
          (SELECT a FROM Anagrafica a WHERE 
               a.codiceFiscale LIKE :pagante OR 
               a.nome LIKE :pagante OR a.cognome LIKE :pagante
          )
       )
```

works good.

Comment: Show us your entities.

Answer (score 0):

The query in the error does not match the query in your example.  If you read the error, it references a query that look like

`SELECT ...
WHERE t0.NRPOLIZZA IN (
    SELECT t1.NRPOLIZZA, t1.DATAINIZIO, ...`

I'm not sure what your code looks like, but my guess is that you are looking at the wrong bit of code.  Are you using a '*' somewhere in your code?

** Another thought, you are using the same alias twice.  Try not using 'p' twice.  I don't know Derby, but worth a try...

Comment: Hi, yes, this is the only query I use in my code: i print it also before I do the 'u = em.createQuery(query);' . I did also a change of the alias, but this doesn't solve the problem. It looks to me that when the query is translated by the JPA engine, there is an error, and instead to select just one column, it's selected all the table.

Comment: Wow, I'm glad you were able to solve it.  I'm not sure I could have ever guessed that.  :-D